# Pipeline get tag list

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-blueocean

I am trying to get the latest tag from a repo Jenkinsfile (using Blue Ocean Declarative Pipelines) but it throws an error.

Command:

```
def tag = sh(script: 'git describe --tags $(git rev-list --tags --max-count=1)', returnStdout: true).trim()
```

Expected output:

```
v2.4.1
```

But I get:

```
fatal: No names found, cannot describe anything.
```

I went into the workspace and executed the command manually and received the same fatal error but when I clone manually I am able to get the version. Am I missing something with Jenkins Pipelines?

Note: I am able to get the commit id and branch name. Not the tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is described here: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-45164

Instead of using checkout scm use:

```
checkout([
    $class: 'GitSCM',
    branches: scm.branches,
    doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: scm.doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations,
    extensions: [[$class: 'CloneOption', noTags: false, shallow: false, depth: 0, reference: '']],
    userRemoteConfigs: scm.userRemoteConfigs,
])
```

Note, it will require by approving script access to methods scm.branches, scm.userRemoteConfigs etc

Comment: Thanks @Alexander ,this exactly what I need after 3 hours try to understand how to fetch tag on pipeline

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that pipelines do not fetch tags. You have to go into the advanced clone settings and enable fetch tags.

Comment: This worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

**1. Git command to print all tags**

1. Clone project into specific directory
2. GO to that that directory
3. Run following command to print all tags

> git for-each-ref --sort=-taggerdate --format '%(tag)' refs/tags

**2. Jenkin pipeline script to print all tags**

```
def latestTag
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Example') {
            steps {
                script {
                    dir('git-source-code') {
                          git(
                            url: "http://35.202.231.233:8082/cicd-test/pegasus-api-gateway.git",
                            credentialsId: 'pankaj.shinde.gitlab.credentials',
                            branch: "master"
                          )      
                          def tagList = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "git for-each-ref --sort=-taggerdate --format '%(tag)' refs/tags").split()
                          tagList.each { nxtTag ->
                              echo nxtTag
                          }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Above two examples sorts tags by tagger date, options we can use are, *objectsize, authordate, committerdate and taggerdate*.

References:
https://www.nico.schottelius.org/blog/how-to-show-the-latest-git-tag/